# how do I declare typed arrays in Safari? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, safari

```
var ui8a = new Uint8Array();
```

fails for me in Safari 5.0.5 (7533.21.1) with an error message of

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Uint8Array
```

printed to console.  But Web searches seem to indicate that [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays) have been [supported in Webkit for a few months now](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.opendarwin.webkit.devel/14678).  Have they not made it into Safari yet, or am I not instantiating them using the right name, or what?

thanks

Comment: Better docs for what poster is talking about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays

Comment: thanks - I've edited the original question to include that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is only available in Firefox 4 and WebKit Nightlies/Chrome 11